# Who owns /var/log/tor logs? Can`t start tor

Tags: raspbian, logfiles

I compiled and installed tor on minibian.
All I must do now is to start tor with `tor`.

But all I get is

```
Mar 15 16:51:36.713 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1k and Zlib 1.2.8.
Mar 15 16:51:36.716 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Mar 15 16:51:36.718 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc".
Mar 15 16:51:36.757 [notice] Based on detected system memory, MaxMemInQueues is set to 278 MB. You can override this by setting MaxMemInQueues by hand.
Mar 15 16:51:36.774 [notice] Opening OR listener on 0.0.0.0:443
Mar 15 16:51:36.778 [notice] Opening Directory listener on 0.0.0.0:80
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [warn] Couldn't open file for 'Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log': Permission denied
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [notice] Closing partially-constructed OR listener on 0.0.0.0:443
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Directory listener on 0.0.0.0:80
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to init Log options. See logs for details.
Mar 15 16:51:36.000 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

With `sudo tor` there's no problem and it runs smoothly but normally I don't have run tor as root.
Now I don´t know how to deal with the ownership of the logs. 
When I do `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/log/tor` tor runs but then there's less security.

```
root@Debian:/var/log# ls -al /usr/local/bin/tor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 debian-tor adm 2091616 Mär 15 14:58 /usr/local/bin/tor
```

Thanx!

Comment: That shows the owner as debian-tor.  So you'll need to ensure that any files written by tor are owned by debian-tor or have debiab-tor as a group member with write permission.

Comment: ls -al /var/log/tor                                                                                   `drwxrws---  2 debian-tor  debian-tor   4096 Mär 15 06:25 tor`

Comment: The d indicates a directory.  Are all the files in that directory owned by debian-tor?

Comment: Yes! `ls -al /var/log/tor/` -> `-rw-r----- 1 debian-tor debian-tor    20742 Mär 15 16:46 notices.log`

Comment: Then perhaps tor isn't being run as debian-tor?  Try a ps aux | grep tor while it is running and see who owns the process.

Comment: `torpi      936 86.0  1.0   6964  3876 pts/1    R+   17:57   0:00 tor` The user torpi runs it, but torpi is also member of the group debian-tor. `debian-tor:x:113:torpi`

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work.  torpi is a group member who only has read access to the various log files.  However I don't understand permissions so will not commit myself further.

Answer (score 1):

Success! :-D
I changed the rights of the logs with `chmod 660 *`.
This is the result:

`-rw-rw---- 1 debian-tor debian-tor    25124 Mär 15 20:49 notices.log`.

And the log folder /var/log/tor

`drwxr-s---  2 debian-tor  debian-tor   4096 Mär 15 06:25 tor`

goes like this.

Thanx!